# CloudKit Fetch record with CKRecordID

Tags: cloudkit, ckrecord, ckfetchrecordchangesopera

I have a problem with fetching a record from iCloud. I want to access a fetched record and assign one value from the key-value pair.

I already tried:

```
currentRecord.object(forKey:)
currentRecord.value(forKey:)
currentRecord.value(forKeyPath:
```

Here is my fetchRecord method:

```
public func fetchRecord(_ recordID: CKRecordID) -> Void {
        let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
        var recordIDArray: [CKRecordID] = []
        recordIDArray.append(recordID)
        let fetchRecordsWithID = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: recordIDArray)
        fetchRecordsWithID.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { (records, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                    self.currentRecord = records?[recordID]
                    print("\(self.currentRecord)")
                    print("ALL KEYS: \(self.currentRecord.allKeys())")

                    self.companyNameLabel.text = self.currentRecord.value(forKeyPath: "companyName") as? String// as? String //object(forKey: "companyName") as? String
//                    self.companyStreetLabel.text = record!.object(forKey: "companyStreet") as? String
//                    self.companyZipCodeLabel.text = record!.object(forKey: "companyZipCode") as? String
//                    self.companyCityLabel.text = record!.object(forKey: "companyCity") as? String
//                    self.companyPhoneLabel.text = record!.object(forKey: "companyPhone") as? String
//                    self.companyEmailLabel.text = record!.object(forKey: "companyEmail") as? String

                }

            }
        }
```

Result of:

```
print("\(self.currentRecord)")
```

is:

```
{
    creatorUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x170021800; recordName=__defaultOwner__, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
    lastModifiedUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x17002d420; recordName=__defaultOwner__, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
    creationDate -> 2017-02-24 16:39:21 +0000
    modificationDate -> 2017-02-24 17:18:54 +0000
    modifiedByDevice -> iCloud
    companyStreet -> "Street"
    companyCity -> "City"
    companyPhone -> "+49 123456136"
    companyEmail -> "info@abc.de"
    companyName -> "PKP"
    companyZipCode -> "12356"
})
```

Everything seems fine with the record

```
print("ALL KEYS: \(self.currentRecord.allKeys())")
```

Result:

```
ALL KEYS: ["companyStreet", "companyCity", "companyPhone", "companyEmail", "companyName", "companyZipCode"]
```

If I want to assign the value of the key "companyStreet" to my label, it returns nil:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-02-24 18:19:55.239907 XYZ[4868:976786] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

**EDIT -> SOLVED**
I finally solved my problem. The problem was my appDelegate, trying to handle my CKNotification. Instead of referencing to my existing TableViewController (embedded in a Navigation Controller - TabBarController) I created a new instance of my TableViewController.